# How do I force lowercase routes in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

When I use ASP.NET Core identity in the following way:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityUserDbContext>()
            .AddSignInManager()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

The framework uses capitalized routes. For example, it redirects to `/Account/Login` when the user is not authenticated. I would like it to redirect to `/account/login`. Is there a way to force it to use all lowercase routes, or is there a way to customize each route individually? I have tried the following option, but it didn't have any effect:

```cs
builder.Services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

How can I make ASP.NET Identity use lowercase routes, ideally without a middleware that redirects to the lowercase version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the following after the `services.AddIdentity(...)` block:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(
            o =>
            {
                o.LoginPath = "/account/login";
                o.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
            });
```